# Why that JS file is loaded twice under net tab of Firebug?

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I run the below page which is just HTML one with extjs files, after loading I inspect Firebug, so in in Firebug under "net" shows all requests which are a total of 5...but the problem is that ***ext-all-debug.js is loaded twice*** but the other JS and CSS are loaded once...I am just wondering as why it is loaded twice...pls check below code and advise me..
thanks in advance....

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title>

        <!-- ** CSS ** -->
        <!-- base library -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/css/ext-all.css" />
        <!-- overrides to base library -->

        <!-- ** Javascript ** -->
        <!-- ExtJS library: base/adapter -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!-- ExtJS library: all widgets -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

        <!-- overrides to library -->

        <!-- extensions -->

        <!-- page specific -->

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you take out your `<script>` tag that loads the file, is it still loaded once?

Comment: not clear, as it is an external js file, so we need to use script tag, right?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I suggested the experiment.

Answer (score 3):

If you include bootstrap.js, it will automatically load the Ext-Libraries.

- If you are local (that means, localhost, any IP-adress or file://
  url) this is **`ext-all-debug.js.`**
- **`ext-all.js`** otherwise.

Just use bootstrap.js or **`ext-all-debug.js`** exclusively.